# Firebase custom auth with Gigya

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, jwt, gigya

My goal is to integrate Firebase Realtime Database within my Android app which already has an authentication layer (Gigya) that isn't managed by me.

The DB structure could be:

```
{
 "users": 
     "gigya_id1": {
          // user's objects
    },
     "gigya_id2": {
          // user's objects
    }, 

    .....
}
```

I also want to add a little of security and rules to avoiding that a user can't READ/WRITE other users stuff.

I read about [firebase custom auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) but as I said, I don't have access to backend (and there is not doc about gigya custom token and firebase integration)

Does anyone have experienced with an integration like this one?

Comment: what do you mean "custom auth"? OAuth 2.0 without using the SDK? If you don't have access to the backend, or a key with permissions, there isn't too much you can do.

Comment: tried to edit my comment but waited too long. You know gigya is the authenticator? why are you trying to add another auth layer on top of gigya? Can you post a use-case of exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved pretty easily.

You can pull the JWT from Gigya whenever a user authenticates by calling to

```
gigya.accounts.getJWT()
```

And pass the JWT in the response from Gigya to the custom auth method in Firebase, following this guidelines: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth